# file writing using blockingcollection

Tags: c#, producer-consumer, blockingcollection

I have a tcp listener which listens and writes data from the server. I used a `BlockingCollection` to store data. Here I don't know when the file ends. So, my filestream is always open.

Part of my code is:

```
private static BlockingCollection<string> Buffer = new   BlockingCollection<string>();

Process()

{
 var consumer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>WriteData());
 while()

 {
  string request = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
  Buffer.Add(request);
 }
} 

WriteData()
{
  FileStream fStream = new FileStream(filename,FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.Write, 16392);

 foreach(var val in Buffer.GetConsumingEnumerable(token))
 {

 fStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(val), 0, val.Length);
                            fStream.Flush();
 }

}
```

The problem is I cannot dispose filestream within loop otherwise I have to create filestream for each line and the loop may never end.

Comment: How about disposing it after the loop in a using statement? What is the question actually?

Comment: Blockingcollection is being populated continuously by the producer and the consumer should wait for next future data.

Comment: When does  the producer ends then?

Comment: If you are using .NET 4.5, you should use an [ActionBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  to post lines to it and have them processed asynchronously. The ActionBlock buffers incoming data so you don't have to.

Comment: thanks, Panagiotis Kanavos.any sample :)?

Answer (score 0):

This would be much easier in .NET 4.5 if you used a DataFlow [ActionBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). An ActionBlock accepts and buffers incoming messages and processes them asynchronously using one or more Tasks.

You could write something like this:

```
public static async Task ProcessFile(string sourceFileName,string targetFileName)
{
    //Pass the target stream as part of the message to avoid globals
    var block = new ActionBlock<Tuple<string, FileStream>>(async tuple =>
    {
        var line = tuple.Item1;
        var stream = tuple.Item2;
        await stream.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line), 0, line.Length);
    });


    //Post lines to block
    using (var targetStream = new FileStream(targetFileName, FileMode.Append, 
                                   FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write, 16392))
    {
        using (var sourceStream = File.OpenRead(sourceFileName))
        {
            await PostLines(sourceStream, targetStream, block);
        }
        //Tell the block we are done
        block.Complete();
        //And wait fo it to finish
        await block.Completion;
    }

}

private static async Task PostLines(FileStream sourceStream, FileStream targetStream, 
                                    ActionBlock<Tuple<string, FileStream>> block)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(sourceStream))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
            if (line == null)
                break;
            var tuple = Tuple.Create(line, targetStream);
            block.Post(tuple);
        }
    }
}
```

Most of the code deals with reading each line and posting it to the block. By default, an ActionBlock uses only a single Task to process one message at a time, which is fine in this scenario. More tasks can be used if needed to process data in parallel.

Once all lines are read, we notify the block with a call to `Complete` and await for it to finish processing with `await block.Completion`.

Once the block's `Completion` task finishes we can close the target stream.

The beauty of the DataFlow library is that you can link multiple blocks together, to create a pipeline of processing steps. ActionBlock is typically the final step in such a chain. The library takes care to pass data from one block to the next and propagate completion down the chain.

For example, one step can read files from a log, a second can parse them with a regex to find specific patterns (eg error messages) and pass them on, a third can receive the error messages and write them to another file. Each step will execute on a different thread, with intermediate messages buffered at each step.